# Systemd stop another service when one is starting

Tags: systemd

For example I have serveral services that normally conflict with each other (same port, etc). But I never need them running at the same time. So for example if I start service `a`, it checks if `b` or `c` is running and stops them? If the other services aren't running, then it just starts `b` normally. But if they are, it sends a `stop` command to the other service(s).

As a workaround right now, I just have a .sh that runs `systemctl stop a.service` then a while loop that greps `systemctl status a.service` until it returns stopped, then runs `systemctl stop c.service` then a while loop that greps `systemctl status c.service` until it returns stopped. After both return stopped, then it runs `systemctl start b.service`. Then I made the same files, but for starting `a.service` and `c.service`, but this workaround is preetty messy imo and I was wondering if there was something official.

Comment: if I start service a, it checks if b or c is running and stops them? If the other services aren't running, then it just starts b normally. But if they are, it sends a stop command to the other service(s). Too weird,  sounds X-Y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`systemd.unit(5)`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Conflicts=):

> Conflicts=
>
> A space-separated list of unit names. Configures negative requirement dependencies. If a unit has a Conflicts= setting on another unit, starting the former will stop the latter and vice versa.
>
> Note that this setting does not imply an ordering dependency, similarly to the Wants= and Requires= dependencies described above. This means that to ensure that the conflicting unit is stopped before the other unit is started, an After= or Before= dependency must be declared. It doesn't matter which of the two ordering dependencies is used, because stop jobs are always ordered before start jobs, see the discussion in Before=/After= below.
>
> If unit A that conflicts with unit B is scheduled to be started at the same time as B, the transaction will either fail (in case both are required parts of the transaction) or be modified to be fixed (in case one or both jobs are not a required part of the transaction). In the latter case, the job that is not required will be removed, or in case both are not required, the unit that conflicts will be started and the unit that is conflicted is stopped.

So if you want to kill `B` and `C` whenever you start `A`, simply add this to the `[Unit]` section of `A.service`

```
[Unit]
Conflicts=B.service C.service
```

If you make all three units `Conflict=` with each other, then you will choose which one you want running.  So starting A will kill B&C, starting B will kill A&C and starting C will kill A&B.

It sounds like you want `B.service` running by default, so only that one should have a `WantedBy=multi-user.target` relationship.  Don't add that to the others (or don't enable them), or they'll all try starting on boot and they will all either fail or a random one will be left running.

It also sounds like you want `B.service` to start whenever you stop `A.service` or `C.service`.  Try to think more about what you want, than what you don't want.  Systemd doesn't have a relationship which starts one unit on the shutdown of another.   To shutdown an entire system, systemd raises [`shutdown.target`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#shutdown.target) which conflicts with everything, bringing them down.  Imagine if C stops to shutdown, starting B during the shutdown procedure.